# How can I modify the Location of my web site in Windows azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

When configured my website on windows azure, I chose Est of USA for the Web site, and North Europe for database.

As you can guess, the performances are very bad, most of my users are in Europe.
Looking on msdn, they said it is not possible to change database of location.

So how can I change the location of my web site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to redeploy your website code to a new Web Site, located in Europe. If you're using git, this should be as simple as setting up a new remote location to the new Web Site and re-doing a push.

In the future: Always deploy website + database in the same datacenter. This avoids performance latency as well as data egress costs out of the data center.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I wanted to avoid but if there is no other solution!

Comment: Deploying your website should be relatively quick and simple. Note that if you've got DNS pointing your domain to your site, you might want to decrease your domain's CNAME/A records' TTL ASAP. Then deploy your site to the correct location, point your DNS records at your new site location and increase the TTL.

Comment: You can also call support to get them to move it over, however, the quickest route especially when you have all of the application code is to redeploy to a different region.