# Azure Resource Group split into different regions

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Apologies I am quite new to Azure.

I have setup an Azure RG but for some reason the **App Service** and **App Service Plan** are located in **South Central US**.  I think it may be slowing down the performance?  How do I move everything to use **UK South**?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason I was thinking about moving the resources to the other resource group, not the other region. So the answer is: No. You can't do that for WebApps yet. You would have to create a new WebApp and new App Service Plan and deploy your code there.

[How can I modify the Location of my web site in Windows azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312781/how-can-i-modify-the-location-of-my-web-site-in-windows-azure)

Answer (score 0):

If you have source code, It is the simplest way to redeploy your application to another new web app. If you do not have source code, please try to use clone via the following steps:

1) create a new web service plan with region "UK Source", select pricing tier as P1 at least (Clone app is a feature that is only available to apps hosted on Premium App Service Plans. You can upgrade your App Service Plan to get access to this feature).

2) Clone Web App in Azure portal. Refer to more information at [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-app-cloning-portal/). Choose the same resource group, select app service plan we created at step 1.

3) delete unused App service plan

4) Change App service plan that we created at step 1.